# what is Dlen in SAS Viewer when I check the property of a dataset?

Tags: sas

I want to create a character variable which lenght is $300. . However, when I created that, the format is $200. and the Dlen is 15, is Dlen*Format=Len in SAS Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

For references see: 
https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Maximum-lengh-of-a-string/td-p/52671?nobounce

Seems to be working with the following example:

```
data foobar;
    length longchar $ 1024;
    input longChar;
    datalines;
    /*Your long Char here*/ 
   ;
run;
```